# Azure built in policy container-no-privilege-escalation preventing "az aks command invoke"

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-policy

I am unable to use "az aks command invoke" because the policy at
https://store.policy.core.windows.net/kubernetes/container-no-privilege-escalation/v3/template.yaml
is preventing privilege escalation. I get the following error when I try it

```
 (KubernetesOperationError) Failed to run command in managed cluster due to kubernetes failure. details: admission webhook "validation.gatekeeper.sh" denied the request: [azurepolicy-k8sazurev3noprivilegeescalatio-adff37e713cffbf58639] Privilege escalation container is not allowed: init-command
[azurepolicy-k8sazurev3noprivilegeescalatio-adff37e713cffbf58639] Privilege escalation container is not allowed: user-command
Code: KubernetesOperationError
Message: Failed to run command in managed cluster due to kubernetes failure. details: admission webhook "validation.gatekeeper.sh" denied the request: [azurepolicy-k8sazurev3noprivilegeescalatio-adff37e713cffbf58639] Privilege escalation container is not allowed: init-command
[azurepolicy-k8sazurev3noprivilegeescalatio-adff37e713cffbf58639] Privilege escalation container is not allowed: user-command
```

Is this an expected ramification of having the AKS built in policies applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected `az aks command invoke` not to work if the policy to prevent privilege escalation containers is applied.

If you have specific Azure Policies, that can result in `az aks command invoke` to fail, because that may not allow specific configuration of the `command-<ID>` pod.

It is recommended to exempt the `aks-command` namespace for the associated Azure Policies which do not allow the pod creation.

You can do that by accessing Azure Portal -> Policy -> Assignments -> identify the assignment(s) and access them -> Edit assignment -> Parameters -> uncheck “Only show parameters that need input or review” box -> add “aks-command” under “Namespace exclusions”.

Alternatively, you can check “command-” pod’s configuration and adjust the policy accordingly (if it’s not a built-in one).